# SVN merge with date from past

Tags: svn, version-control

Is it possible to merge a branch into trunk with a date from past?

For example I'm making a merge today, 17/01/2017 and I want to have it with a date 31/12/2016.

If that's possible, how to check if something like this was done?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to merge a branch into trunk with a date from past?

*Short answer* is **No**.

*Longer answer* is *It depends*, but still **No**.

When you commit the result of merge operation, it creates a new revision in the repository. Let's say r1005. The date and time of the revision will be specified of the time of this commit. However, an administrator could adjust the date and time.

Users will immediately notice that the previous revision r1004 has commit date of e.g. 01/07/2016, but r1005 commit date was altered and set to e.g. 01/07/2014. This can not normally happen unless you practice time travel.

Read about `svn:date` and unversioned properties in [SVNBook | Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html).

> For example I'm making a merge today, 17/01/2017 and I want to have it
>   with a date 31/12/2016.

A regular user can't modify unversioned properties, by default. Only administrator with local access to the repositories can.

> If that's possible, how to check if something like this was done?

If an administrator adjusted an unversioned property using admin tools, you won't see any special evidence about that. But in case regular user adjusted unversioned property via HTTP(S), you could check SVN server's [Operational log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.operational-logging.html) (aka High-level logging).

Search for the log events related to the revision in question.

- Such event should be logged when a user commits revision 1234 to
  repository MyRepo. The event specifies the originating IP address of
  the commit, authenticated user's name and date & time of the original commit.

  > commit r1234
  >
  > Repository: MyRepo
  >
  > User:
  >
  > Host:
- Such event should be logged when someone modifies 1234 revision's
  svn:date property over HTTP(S). The event specifies the originating
  IP and the name of the user who changed the value of the svn:date
  revision.

  > change-rev-prop r1234 svn:date
  >
  > Repository: MyRepo
  >
  > User:
  >
  > Host:

You could use the same approach to check whether someone modified commit's author username `svn:author` or any other unversioned property.